# alternative of java.math.BigInteger.bitCount()? required or not?

Tags: java, biginteger

I see uses of depreacted members in

```
java.math.BigInteger.bitCount()
```

Is there an alternative for the same or we dont need it? since the values is being computed if not initialized.

Just wanted to confirm my assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need an alternative, it works fine and will continue to do so (some when in the future it will get rid of its deprecated parts but that should not be your concern.)

The deprecated code in there is used to let other JDK Developers know that they SHALL NOT use the variable bitCount but use the method bitCount() instead.

Comment: If my code is using it, shouldn't it be my concern also...
Isn't deprecated is way to let people know that this should not be used.

Comment: See, the method itself is not deprecated. So the JDK Developers let you know that its fine to use it. The deprecated code in there is used to let other JDK Developers know that they SHALL NOT use the variable bitCount but use the method bitCount() instead.